# co-living and co-evolving

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Today I had a thought a problem I couldn't resolve it on my own. I just can't realize what people will think right after they hear others using the word "co-living" and "co-evolving". I mean a particular thought of any specific information that comes to mind once you may hear I say "they have co-lived and co-evolved since then", for example.

Another example I doubt if their use is truly versatile and correct,

```
Your and my native languages have been co-living and co-evolving for hundreds of years
```

Comment: Hi @Aussay! I'm not sure I understand what your question is. Are you asking for a definition, or do you want help re-phrasing you sentence, or are you wondering whether such a word exists?

Comment: We say *co-existing*, not *co-living*. For reasons I can't explain straight off, I would say *Yours and my language* (not *Your and my*) but other than that your example is fine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Your native language and mine ..."

Comment: @FumbleFingers: If we're using possessive pronouns, wouldn't it be more usual to say 'Your language and mine' or 'My language and yours'?

Comment: "Your and my native languages" is grammatically correct because it can be parsed into "Your native language and my native language", but it's definitely not the _friendliest_ construction as others have pointed out.

Comment: @Aussay Marshal: If you rewrite you question so that it actually asks an answerable question, we might vote to reopen. As it stands it is not clear what you want.

Comment: @Barrie England: In Google Books I found 2 each for *"Your/s and my language"* - with *"your/s and my parents"* it was 9 for *"yours"* and 10 for *"your"*, but with *"houses"* it was 4:2 the other way. Weird, huh? I sense a question coming on...

Comment: @Tom Raywood: If you'd like to set your thoughts out about this on [my newly-asked question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55722/), be warned I will ask you to expand on exactly what you mean by *"not the friendliest construction"*. I'll admit I personally don't like *"Your" here, but obviously not everyone feels that way, so in what sense is it "unfriendly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Co-evolving* is an established word, at least among evolutionary scientists.

*Co-living* is not an established word.

*Cohabiting* is such a well established word that it doesn't even need a hyphen, and has the meaning that you might expect from *co-living*.

Although we sometimes describe a language as "living", it's not clear to me that a pair of languages could "cohabit", however. Try *coexisting* instead.