# “in you_ and your family’s best interests”

Tags: possessives, personal-pronouns, ellipses, compound-possessives

I’ve seen this picture of a leaflet being [tweeted](https://twitter.com/supersole/status/722053358777933824) today. It’s supposedly issued by the UK government and distributed widely:

[image: The referendum is a once in a generation decision. The Government believes it is in you and your family’s best interests that the UK remains in the European Union.]

Am I overlooking something or does it really contain the grammar error discussed in ["You and your" vs. "Your and your"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100572/you-and-your-vs-your-and-your)?

I could see the possessive `’s` applying to the whole phrase

> *it is in (you and your family)’s best interests*,

because the plural *interests* wouldn’t properly match singular *your*, i.e. it’s a short form of either of

> - it is in your best interest and in your family’s best interest
> - it is in your best interest and in your family’s best interest**s**

instead of

> - it is in your best interest**s** and in your family’s best interest**s**

Comment: It's a typo probably. Also, it should read: once-in-a-generation decision. The EU is well known for this kind of scrappy writing.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, I would have put hyphens there, too, but then I’m German. I would also have expected either “June 23rd, 2016” or “23 June 2016”, but I’m not well versed in British conventions. Please spare the rants for elsewhere.

Comment: 23 June 2106 is usual BrE. What rants? What allows you to say that to me? It is a fact, but I guess that might be not known by a callow youth. There's always time to learn: http://ec.europa.eu/translation/english/guidelines/documents/misused_english_terminology_eu_publications_en.pdf Also, this: please spare us your rants. You can't spare rants for elsewhere.

Comment: To me, it's the sort of pedantry that most native English speakers can't be bothered with.  Does anybody not understand what it means?

Comment: "You and your family" is a common expression, e.g. in "we invite you and your family to join us". It may then be considered as a nominal group, to which the genetive case can be applied, like in "a husband and wife's story".

Comment: @SimonB. When a non-native speaker asks a serious question about correct English usage you should not dismiss this as "pedantry". Some people do actually care about good English.

Comment: @Crissov  The most common UK format for dates is 'day month year' - both *23rd June 2016* and *23 June 2016* are perfectly acceptable & common.  The format 'month day year' is more common in the USA.

Comment: @Lambie You say "The EU is well known for this kind of scrappy writing.", but it's a leaflet from the British Government - not from the EU!

Comment: @Crissov You state "the plural interests wouldn’t properly match singular your".  "Interests" is very commonly used in the plural because each person has multiple interests.

Comment: And while we're pulling the government's leaflet apart, shouldn't the last clause strictly be in the conditional tense: "... that the UK *remain* in the European Union" (not *remain**s***)?

Answer (score 1):

"I could see the possessive ’s applying to the whole phrase"

You are right. This is normal idiomatic English. Like "the girl I used to go with's father".