# Is “Joe’s and my bicycles” correct?

Tags: subjects, compound-possessives

Is this phrasing correct and acceptable?

> Here are Joe’s and my bicycles

I am describing two bicycles, one owned by Joe and one owned by myself.

Comment: Why do you think it might be incorrect or inacceptable?

Comment: Also related: [What possessive forms are used for mutual first-person ownership](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8520/what-possessive-forms-are-used-for-mutual-1st-person-ownership), [“Your and my X” vs “Yours and my X”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55722/your-and-my-something-vs-yours-and-my), [“My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner), and the related questions linked from these.