# Double possession dilemma: should I say “your” or “yours”?

Tags: possessives, compound-possessives, possessive-pronouns, double-possessive

What is the best way to say this?

> Because of **yours** and the John Wichel Foundation’s grant we are able to continue our mission to serve all Texans with diabetes.

Should it be

> Because of **your** and John Wichel Foundation's grant, we are able . . . 
>   OR
>   Because of yours and the John Wichel Foundation's grant, we are able . . .

It's a double possessive with the word *your*.  No matter how I write it, it doesn't sound right.

Comment: *Because of your and the JFW's grant...* sounds fine to me. Re-wording is always an option.

Comment: "The grants from both yourself and the John Wichel Foundation have enabled us to ..." avoids the problem.

Comment: Note that there is one more possibility in spoken Southern American English: "Is this mine or yorn?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What possessive forms are used for mutual 1st person ownership?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8520/what-possessive-forms-are-used-for-mutual-1st-person-ownership)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Your and my \[something\]" vs "Yours and my..."](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55722/your-and-my-something-vs-yours-and-my)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4226/2085)

Comment: @tchrist: I don't think that last one's a good duplication target, for the reasons I outline in this Meta post: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7109/can-we-switch-to-a-better-canonical-question-about-using-pronouns-in-compound-po (Edit: I just noticed, you also posted a comment that seemed to indicate agreement.)

Comment: @sumelic Only my first one is "real". :)

Comment: *Because of your grant and also JW Foundation's, we are able to continue ...* should do the trick.

Comment: One assumes that there are two grants involved here, but it's also possible that there is one grant provided jointly by the Foundation and the person being addressed. The choice of grammatical form would be affected by this.

Comment: 'Double possessives' is a term usually reserved for the strange but idiomatic forms 'a friend of mine / yours / his / hers / theirs / John's .... This is joint possession / association.

Answer (score 2):

When using them separately, we'd use-

- Your grant...
- John Wichel Foundation's grant...

When using them together, combining them with an 'and'-

...your and John Wichel Foundation's grants...

... which, when placed into the context of this sentence, would be-
"Because of your and the John Wichel Foundation’s grants, we are able to continue our mission to serve all Texans with diabetes."

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but do you think the pluaralization on "grant" is grammatically necessary? I think it helps facilitate the (likely) intended meaning, but the same meaning is accessible by dropping the plural.

Comment: @Silenus If they made more than one grant, pluralize grant. If they made one grant, it remains singular—no s.

Comment: @Stan, fair enough. I guess I was wondering about the grammaticality of sentences like: "Your and my dog play great together." This sounds fine to me despite the fact that 'dog' is not plural. There is an elided 'dog' after 'your.' The same could happen with 'grant'.

Comment: @Silenus "Your dog and *mine* play great together," might be easier on the ear.

Comment: Thank you guys!  I had no idea my post was answered!

Answer (score 1):

Kapeezy's is the logical answer, but we don't always speak logically.

My sense is that *yours and the John Wichel Foundation’s grant* is not that uncommon.

I had a look at the iWeb corpus, searching for *your[s] and someone else's*.

I found that *yours and someone else's* had 108 hits, but I count around 36 of them before noun phrases (like "grant"), and the rest in contexts where you would expect *yours* on its one (eg *Love a kid today - yours or someone else's.*). *Your or someone else's* got 48 hits, all of them before NPs.

On the basis of that (one) corpus, then, *your* is more common in that context, but not overwhelmingly so. The GloWbE corpus gave me smaller numbers, but the same relationship: 6 *your* to 5 *yours*. On the other hand, the NOW corpus (News on the Web, so presumably mostly professionally written) has a much larger difference: 285 to 5.

Comment: We've got to go with the science. But with small sample sizes, the noisiest, not perhaps the best role models, tend to get heard.

Comment: I’m not surprised that variations occur. There are many possibilities **1** {Poss. Adj.} and {Poss. Adj. + noun.} – Her and my bike have been stolen. **2** {Poss. Adj. + noun} and {Poss. Adj. + noun} - Her bike and my bike have been stolen. **3** {Poss. Pron.} and {Poss. Adj. noun} – Her**s**, and my bike, has been stolen. **4** {Poss. Adj. + noun} and {Poss. Pron.} – Her bike and mine have been stolen. **5** {Poss. Pron.} and {Poss. Pron.} - Her**s** and mine have been stolen.

Comment: @Greybeard: yes. It's one of the areas where native speakers are often unsure.

Answer (score -1):

A: Why are the police at school?

B: A bike has been stolen

A: Whose?

B(i): ***Your*** or someone else's **bike** – **Your** is a possessive **adjective** (and determiner) and must have a noun as its subject

Or

B(ii):***Yours*** or someone else's – **Yours** is a possessive pronoun and cannot accept a noun.

**someone else's** is a genitive and as such it can act as a possessive adjective (determiner) **and** as a possessive pronoun.

Compare

It is **mine**

It is **my bike.**

It is **John’s.**

It is **John’s bike.**